# how to subtract between sql row and textbox value php codes?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

i want to subtract a text box value with sql row value, please help me. 
i want this result $Qty = $Qty1 - $QTY2;
is there is any solutions?
**this is my code.**

```
            include('config.php');
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT QTY FROM fab_inv where SUB_FABNO='".$_POST["item_code"][$i]."'");
                        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        $res = $num_rows;
            $_POST['hiddenField3']=$row['QTY'];
            $QTY1 = $_POST['hiddenField3'];
            $QTY2 = $_POST["item_issue"][$i];
            $QTY = $QTY1 - ($QTY2);

            include('config.php');
            $sql="update fab_inv set  QTY=".$QTY." where SUB_FABNO='".$_POST["item_code"][$i]."' ";
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql);
            if(! $retval )
            {
            die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
```

but its inserting only the text box value with minus in front of the value like this. if row qty = 50 and text box value = 30. then its inserting only -30...

Comment: Its not required to include a file again and again just include it once at the top of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And your query structure has a nasty race condition as well. There is **NO** need to run a select then update. You can do it all in a single update:

```
$val = (intval)$_POST['whatever field you want'];
$sql = "UPDATE yourtable SET QTY = QTY - $val WHERE ...."
```

As it stands now, you're sucking a value into the client, doing the math there, then spitting the new value back into the database. What happens if this particular copy of the script gets suspended for a short time, and some **OTHER** User hits the same script? Now you'll have:

```
client #1: $qty = 50, database qty = 50
client #1: $qty - 40 = 10; database qty = 50
client #2: $qty = 50, database qty = 50
client #2: $qty - 10 = 40, database qty = 50
client #2: update database -> qty = 40
client #1: update database -> qty = 10
```

oops. Now you've sold 50 items, but still show 10 in stock.

Comment: Thank you Mr.@marcB. i am new to php jquary and mysql.. i cant understand this answer can u explain?